# How to get this "hello='23'" in place of this "hello=\'23\'"

Tags: python

I am trying to do this code

```
vi = "--get"
x = "hello='"
cm = "'"
c = '='
v = '"'
w = "Hello, world"
num = raw_input()
hi = (vi+c+v+x+num+cm+v)
print (hi,w)
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
clipboard.set_text(str(vi+c+v+x+num+cm+v))
clipboard.store()
```

And when I print, it prints the number with this ' '.

How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in order to represent the tuple, `(hi,w)` python needs to escape the interior single quotes.  That's because python is choosing to enclose hi with single quotes because the first quote that it finds in `hi` is a double quote.

You don't need to care about that though, because:

```
vi = "--get"
x = "hello='"
cm = "'"
c = '='
v = '"'
w = "Hello, world"
num = "23"
hi = (vi+c+v+x+num+cm+v)
print (hi,w)
print (hi,w)[0]
```

gives you:

```
('--get="hello=\'23\'"', 'Hello, world')
--get="hello='23'"
```

`('--get="hello=\'23\'"', 'Hello, world')` is how python represents the tuple as a string.  It doesn't mean that the first element of the tuple as the escape sequence in it.  `print (hi,w)[0]` gives you what you expected `--get="hello='23'"`

```
print '({},{})'.format(hi,w)
```

gives you:

```
(--get="hello='23'",Hello, world)
```

See this working example: https://paiza.io/projects/olg0_zf7G3SRsbXcGjSjXQ

**The Point**

`(hi,w)` is an instance of the class `tuple`.  The reason why `print (hi,w)` gives you `('--get="hello=\'23\'"', 'Hello, world')`  is because that's what `tuple.__str__()` is designed to do.

To illustrate the point, lets subclass tuple and override `__str__()` to give the output you require.

```
class MyTuple(tuple):

    def __str__(self):
        return '({},{})'.format(*self)

foo = MyTuple((hi,w))
print foo
```

output:

```
(--get="hello='23'",Hello, world)
```

Overriding tuple is probably not a great idea but it works for this demonstration.

Comment: There is a way to print both at the same time without being affected by the double quote? Thanks¡¡¡ :)

Comment: Sure, `print '({},{})'.format(hi,w)` will give you `(--get="hello='23'",Hello, world)`

Comment: I don't think that I made the point clear though...  I'm making edits to the answer.